# How to modify pointer to structure inside void function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I tried to google my problem many times but never found an answer that fits my problem. I have to modify a pointer to a structure inside a function(fill it with data), and then use that pointer as an argument to another functions. 
I have a text file that has multiple reports in it and I am supposed to count the reports and fill all the data to a pointer to a structure. Which isnt a problem, I allocated memory without a problem, got through the file without a problem and also filled the pointer. But I can't figure out how to use the filled pointer outside of the function.

```
struct report{
  char name[50];
  int id_number;
}

void function1(struct report **ptr){
  //do stuff like count the number of reports in file
  //and allocate memmory for pointer to structure
  //and fill the pointer to structure with data
}
int main() {
  struct report *pointer;
  function(pointer);
  //now I expect variable 'pointer' to be filled and ready to use by another functions
  return 0;
}
```

Can you please suggest some solutions please? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Do you allocate the memory in function1 on the heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct report{
  char name[50];
  int id_number;
};

void foo(struct report **ptr){
  *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct report));  // allocate memory
  (*ptr)->id_number = 42;  // fill the allocated memory
}

int main() {
  struct report *pointer;
  foo(&pointer);  // important part - pass to the foo() pointer to the pointer.

  printf("%d\n", pointer->id_number);

  free(pointer);  // do not forget to free the memory.
  return 0;
}
```